# Handling Uniqueness of concurrent request in Rails database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, concurrency

I have built an application in which SMS Voting is integrated using Wire2sms API.
and also I added uniqueness of answer_id in model. but due to the multiple concurrent request at the same time, model not able to handle it and multiple records are get created with same answer_id. does anyone face this issue? or have any pointers to deal with same

Thanks for Help.

Comment: A same problem is addressed in this blog as well. http://blog.mhartl.com/2008/06/26/working-around-the-validates_uniqueness_of-bug-in-ruby-on-rails/ but looking for a better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is going to be adding a uniqueness constraint to the underlying database. Rails's uniqueness validations are really just supposed to be extra (for prettier errors and such). Since the database will bethe final authority on the data, it should be the one to enforce the constraint.

Comment: Benjamin Thank you for response.can you suggest any other way because db constraints might raise to throw an exception as mine live database already has lot of duplicated value now.

Comment: Can you go through and clean out the old data? It really would be the best way. A possible alternative would be some form of [pessimistic locking](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html) on the answer corresponding to the unique `answer_id`, or a table-wide lock on the model you are inserting.